# RaMap Range using <, >, =

Tags: python, arcgis

I know that for `RemapRange([a,b,c])` where a = lower boundary, b = upper boundary, c = the new category. How would I write a line to make, for example

- Category E = < 0
- Cetegory F = greater than or equal to 0 to less than 5
- Category G = anything greater than or equal to 5

it's from `arcpy.sa`

Comment: Is RemapRange a function you wrote? Or does it come from some module?

Comment: @user1775603: It is a component of ArcGIS; I retagged it to reflect that.

Comment: You might want to try posting this in http://gis.stackexchange.com - they are more active with arcpy.